# How can I remove onEvent from button widget in Corona?

Tags: button, lua, widget, coronasdk

I am trying to remove onEvent listener from button widget. I tried to assign nil to onEvent attribute but it didn't work and lastly I tried this:

```
   buttonWidget : removeEventListener("touch", buttonWidget.onEvent)
```

I have several button like that and it just stopped all button's event listeners. What do you suggest?  How can I remove the event listener for one button widget? Thanks.

Here is how I create my button widgets:

```
for i=0,2 do
 for j=0,8 do
    count=count+1
    letterBtn[count] = widget.newButton{
    id = alphabet[count], 
    left = 5+j*50,
    top = H-160+i*50, 
    label = alphabet[count],
    width = 45,
    height = 45, 
    font = nil, 
    fontSize = 18,
    labelColor = { default = {0,0,0}, over = {255,255,255}},
    onEvent = btnOnEventHandler 
    };
  end
end
```

Can you tell me how can I remove onEvent later?

Okey, I tried Button: setEnabled(false) but still it disables all buttons not just one. I already tried your second advice but it gives the same result. I am copying the rest of the code. Can you please look at it and tell me what I am missing?

```
local function checkLetter(e)
if(guessWord) then
    for i=1, #guessWord do
        local c = guessWord:sub(i,i)
        if c==e.target.id then 
            letter[i].text = e.target.id
            letterCount = letterCount +1
            print("letterCount"..letterCount)
            e.target:setEnabled(false)
        end
    end
    if (letterCount == #guessWord and not hanged) then
        timer.performWithDelay(500, function() 
            letterCount=0
            rightWGuess = rightWGuess+1
            for k,v in pairs(notGuessedWord) do 
                if v == guessWord then  
                notGuessedWord[k]=nil
                end
            end
            enableButtons()
            startGame() end ,1)
    end
end
end



local function btnOnEventHandler(e)
   if(e.phase == "began") then
    checkLetter(e)
    print(e.target.id)
   end
    return true
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete, runnable example showing multiple event registrations and how you're removing them?

Comment: Can you check it now? I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to temporarily (or permanently) stop a button from responding to touch events, you can use [Button:setEnabled(false)](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ButtonWidget/setEnabled.html).

The following worked for me for removing a listener from just 2 buttons. Button 1 and 3 stopped responding to events as expected while 2, 4, and 5 still did.

**Update:** To disable, you have to do it on the 'ended' phase or Corona gets confused.

```
widget = require 'widget'

local function btnOnEventHandler(event)
    print('Event', event.target.id, event.phase)
    if event.phase == 'ended' then
        -- Disable the button so it can't be clicked again
        -- Must disable in the end state or Corona gets 
        -- confused
        event.target:setEnabled(false)
    end
end    

local buttons = {}
for i=1,5 do
    buttons[i] = widget.newButton{
        id = 'button' .. i, 
        left = display.contentCenterX - 50,
        top = 60 * i, 
        label = 'Button ' .. i,
        width = 100,
        height = 50, 
        onEvent = btnOnEventHandler
    }
end

buttons[1]:removeEventListener('touch', buttons[1].onEvent)
buttons[3]:removeEventListener('touch', buttons[3].onEvent)
```

Comment: I tried those but couldn't make it work. Can you please look at my edited question again?